# FreeRadius: Authentication with active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, radius

I need to setup a radius server with active directory authentication, on a RHEL 6.5 server. I have been following [this guide](http://deployingradius.com/documents/configuration/active_directory.html).

As per the guide, I have made necessary configurations which are as follows:

*/etc/samba/smb.conf:*

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP-NAME-HERE
        security = ads
        password server = PASSWORD-SERVER-HERE
        realm = REALM-HERE
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        ...
        ...
```

*/etc/krb5.conf:*

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = REALM-HERE
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 REALM-HERE = {
 kdc = PASSWORD-SERVER-HERE
 }
```

Then, joined the domain successfully.

*/etc/raddb/modules/ntlm_auth:*

```
exec ntlm_auth {
        wait = yes
        program = "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=DOMAIN-HERE --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
}
```

*/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default & /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/inner-module:*

```
...
...
authenticate {
        ntlm_auth
...
...
```

After all these configurations, I made sure that `samba` and `winbind` are running.

But, as soon as I executed `radiusd -X`, it displayed an error below:

```
rlm_eap: SSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
rlm_eap_tls: Error reading certificate file /etc/raddb/certs/server.pem
rlm_eap: Failed to initialize type tls
/etc/raddb/eap.conf[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[313]: Failed to load module "eap".
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[252]: Errors parsing authenticate section.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the line `make_cert_command = "${certdir}/bootstrap"` in `/etc/raddb/eap.conf` file corrected the error.